# How to reduce plot (image) size for `exams2pdf` output?

Tags: r, plot, latex, knitr, r-exams

When I reduce the size of the image in the [`scatterplot.Rmd`](http://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2017-08-14-scatterplot//scatterplot.Rmd)  file  and weave it into `exams2html`, the result is as expected. The same thing happens when I knit the file with the `knitr` button.

I achieve this by modifying the sizes from

```
fig.path = "", fig.cap = ""}
plot(x, y)
```

changing the values of `fig.height` and `fig.width`.

But, when I do the same thing and try to knit with `exams2pdf` output, the image gets distorted or remains the same initial size.

What changes do I need to make to the code so that the result is as expected in the `exams2pdf` output?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

With your settings you control the size of the graphics file that is created. But the default LaTeX template includes all graphics with 80% of the text width. Thus, no matter how large the actual graphics file is (.pdf, .png, ...) it is always embedded in LaTeX/PDF with 80% width.

**Controlling the graphics size**

You can either control the properties of the graphics file by setting the corresponding options in the code chunks in the exercise directly. Namely you can set `fig.height=...` and/or `fig.width=...` as described in your question.

Additionally, you can also not set these options in the exercise file but instead set them in the `exams2xyz()` interface, e.g., `exams2pdf(..., height = ..., width = ...)`. This is convenient if you want different default graphics sizes in PDF output or HTML output, for example.

**Controlling the size of the embedded graphic**

Similarly you can control the size of the embedded graphics in different ways. In the HTML-based output in R/exams the graphics files are typically included "as is". Thus, the size of the graphic in the HTML text is determined by the size of the graphics file.

Alternatively, you can try to control this through code chunk options like `out.width` etc.

Finally, you can set properties in the template of the output document. This is what is implicitly done in the default `plain.tex` template. This uses

```
\usepackage{Sweave}
```

which contains the line

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}
```

by default. But you can suppress this setting by using

```
\usepackage[nogin]{Sweave}
```

Thus, if you modify your LaTeX template accordingly  and call `exams2pdf(..., template = "mytemplate.tex")` then the graphics files are included "as is".